# Код JS работает неправильно

Tags: javascript, css, функции

Нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы автоматически вызывалась функция JS и элемент плавно становился "видимым", вот что мне здесь посоветовали:

HTML:
     Элемент по умолчанию Opacity 0, transition: 3s ease, id = ElementId

JS

```
 <script>
 function nameFunc() {
  document.getElementById("ElementId").style.opacity = '1'; 
  }
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", nameFunc);
  </script>
```

Элемент становится "видимым", НО НЕ плавно, а моментально - уже страница загружается с видимым элементом Opacity: 1. 
Но, если вызывать функцию вручную - всё работает хорошо, анимация работает.
В чем проблема? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: transition: opacity 3s ease ?

Comment: атрибут transition отвечает за анимацию, его у вас в коде не видно

Comment: Я же написал, в начальном стиле элемента transition: 3s ease

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно дело в том, что вы используете DOMContentLoaded.

> Событие DOMContentLoaded происходит когда весь HTML был полностью загружен и пройден парсером, **не дожидаясь окончания загрузки таблиц стилей, изображений и фреймов**.

Попробуйте вместо этого использовать событие load
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: В данном случае функция вообще не срабатывает

Comment: @Holter А вы document на window поменяли ? Должно быть так window.addEventListener("load", nameFunc);

Comment: Так всегда работало нормально, но, я прочел что это старый способ и сейчас используют document

Comment: @Holter Когда работало ? Вы понимаете, что это разные события а не запись одного события разными способами ? DOMContentLoaded у document срабатывает, как видно из названия, по загрузке DOM. DOM не включает себя ресурсы, только HTML структуру. Если вы хотите дождаться загрузки ресурсов (в число которых входят и css файлы), то нужно отлавливать событие load у window.

Comment: Благодарю, Никита Павлов. Разобрался.